# How to add data to two fields in a collection row with SailsJS Waterline update() method

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm creating a forgot password functionality for my application right now, and one critical step I'm struggling with is to add data to two forgot-password related fields when the user begins the forgot password process.

The fields are

1) `resetPasswordToken` - A randomly generated token that will temporarily allow the user to set a new password.

2) `resetPasswordExpires` - A date set for exactly one hour from creation that creates a time limit on how long the password is available to be changed.

I get to a part where I need to update the user row (for the user needing a password change!) with those two fields, and I don't know how to do it. I'm trying to use the [SailsJS Update method](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update) to accomplish this. Before when I had been updating models using the `update()` method I could do so using some standard notation like so:

```
User.update(req.param('id'), req.body)
    .exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) { return res.json(400, err); }
        res.json(users[0]);
    });
```

It was easy because 1. I was updating an entire row at a time, and 2. Because of that, I had the `id` I could pass. Updating the entire row is the only way to use update that I have found to be well documented.

However, now it is much harder. I need to update just two fields, and I don't think I have the `id` available when I do this server-side action. The docs do not specify how to do something like this. I have the `email` address that they used to sign up, which **is** uniqe, so it should be possible. I need to use a `.where()` of some sort I think?

At this point the entire server-side action looks somewhat like this:

```
forgot: function (req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
                var token = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, token);
            });
        },
        function(token, done) {
            User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    done(null, false, { message: 'Email doesn't exist' });
                }

                user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
                // TODO: this part will have to be figured out
                // Have no idea how to update correctly! Left it blank

                User.update( );

                // Above is the key problem
                done(err, token, user);
            });
        },
        function(token, user, done) {
            htmlMessage = '<h4>You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.</h4>' +
                            '<p>Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:</p>' +
                            "<p><a href='http://" + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + "'> Link to password reset </a></p>" +
                            '<p>If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.</p>';

            var emailInfo = {
                to: user.email,
                from: "customerservice@work.com",
                subject: "Password Reset",
                message: htmlMessage,
                fromName: "Random Organization"
            };

            EmailService.simpleSendEmail(emailInfo, function (err) {
                done(err, 'done');
            });
        }
        ], function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.redirect('/login');
        });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. After you have fetched the `User` instance and changed the attributes as required, instead of calling `User.update()`, just call `save()` on the instance:

```
User.findOne({/* criteria */}).exec(function(err, user){
    if (err) handleErrors(err);
    user.property = newValue;//and any other changes you need
    user.save(function(err, savedRecord){
        cb(err, savedRecord);
    });
});
```

To avoid making two database calls, you can use the `update()` method this way:

```
User.update({ email: userEmail },
            { resetPasswordToken: newToken,
              resetPasswordExpires: newExpires })
          .exec( function(err, updatedObjArray) {
                return callback(err, updatedObjArray);
               // Note that an array will be returned even
               // if only a single record has been updated.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the code you've written is right, you just have to change the line that says

```
User.update( );
done(err, token, user);
```

to

```
user.save(function(err){
   done(err, token, user);
});
```

or as @galactocalypse suggested, you can directly use the update query.